# consulta sql como relacionar una atributo de una tabla con datos quemados

Tags: sql, sql-server

hola como estan todos les agradeceria que me ayudaran a resolver una duda mas teorica aver si logro entender como debo crear dos relaciones de tablas en sql.

pasa que estoy haciendo un proyecto de una veterinaria tengo dos tablas medicos y horas trabajadas como lo ven aqui[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto lo hice en exel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que pasa en esta segunda tabla es que el tipo de pago define el salario del medico, pero estos montos deben estar quemados ya que no se digitan yo solo puedo digitar el tipo de pago y en base a ese tipo de pago se debe relacionar a el salario que sale en la tabla, pero realmente no entiendo si para esto deberia crear una tabla independiente o tener todo en la tabla de medico, ya que nose como podria quemar estos montos de salarios y al digitar el tipo de pago que me aparesca ejemplo los montos.

alguien me podria explicar como podria quemar estos datos para que al digitar el tipo de pago estos se muestren sin tener que digitarlos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como podran ver esto es lo que debo hacer pero el proyecto es solo de bd entonces de alli mi inquietud , como puedo crear ese rango fijo de salarios?

Answer (score 0):

La estructura que has creado es correcta, es mejor tener las dos tablas por separado, una con toda la información del medico y otra con los campos relacionados al pago y simplemente hacer un **JOIN**. Entiendo por lo que expones que todo es editable menos los campos **"desde"** y **"hasta"**.

No lo comentas, pero imagino que tu pregunta viene relacionada a que tienes un formulario de alta de medicos. Comprobar la horquilla de horas trabajadas y asignar una forma de pago o otra, debería ser trabajo de tu backend y desde ahí insertar una cosa u otra en la bd. La pregunta es genérica, si me das mas datos puedo editar la respuesta y adaptarla mas a lo que necesitas

Comment: muchas gracias por las sujerencias como veras modifique la pregunta para que puedas ver directamente el enunciado de mi proyecto

Comment: y como comente mi proyecto es solo de base de datos no utilizo c# ni nigun lenguaje de programacion es solamente base de datos de alli mi inquietud de como creo ese rango fijo de sueldos, para que cuando ponga el tipo en la base de datos relacione por hora con el rango correspondiente etc.

Comment: Tienes algún avance en sql? haz intentando algo? Saludos

Comment: @Josue Vargas digamos eso se podria hacer con if en la bd que al yo digitar ciertas palabras lo relacione con un sueldo pero no estoy segura de si esa sea la forma una vez hice un proyecto en la universidad similar pero recuerdo que era mas simple de hacer, solo que ahora no recuerdo bien como lo hice, pero por eso queria preguntar en este foro pero ahorita no e comenzado en sql estoy sacando las tablas y escribiendolas en exel primero

Comment: osea no busco que me pasen codigo con que me expliquen como deberia poderse hacer esto se los agradeceria

Comment: lo que quiero que me puedan explicar es como yo al escribir por hora puedo relacionar esa palabra con un  dato salarial quemado.

Comment: Tu "tabla" _horas trabajadas_ registras las horas que trabajo o como?

Comment: Debes de tener una tabla para relacionar el medico y cuanto esta ganando por hora, semana, mes. Por ejemplo id_medico, columna(cuantas horas trabajo(ingresado como numero)), columna(cuanto gana por hora). Id_medico, 2 , 5,000.  Por ejemplo id_medico, columna(cuantas semanas trabajo), columna (a cuanto le pagan la semana). Por ejemplo id_medico, columna(mes(1)), columna(120.xxxxxx). Ya teniendo eso puedes crear un procedimiento almacenado para realizar el calculo de salario utilizando como referencia esas columnas. Y cuando sea calculado entonces que se imprima en la columna salario

Comment: De tu tabla médicos. Cuando realices el calculo en tu procedimiento almacenado debes emplear un where cuando el id_medico(tabla médicos) sea igual a id_medico(tabla calculo salario).

Comment: Puedes ver este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZvdNYYxyEw,

Comment: Procedimiento almacenado fundamentos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-AxwYHcG2F4